# Razor engine intellisense stop working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, razor, visual-studio-2013

As mentioned in title in my visual studio 2013 intellisense stopped working. I can't retrieve model information and can't even write `@model mynamespace`..

I've tried everything during day what I could find in google:

• unload/reload

• restart vs/windows

• switch to another project (but there is same result)

• tools >> options >> text editor >> all languages >> auto list members/parameter information (they're checked already. I tried uncheck and then check but it's same)

• repair vs

• Tools->Import and Export settings->Reset all settings

Is there any other way?

Comment: Just close and Reopen Visual Studio.

Comment: @SeM I've tried that dozen of times

Comment: Maybe you've changed your .Net version from project properties to earlier versions?

Comment: Have you built your project yet? Razor needs libs in the bin/ directory for intellisense.

Answer (score 1):

If you face this problem on each project, then I suppose that problem may be related to Visual Studio itself. Did you do some update or manipulations with system files during the last days?

Comment: not. once when i did unload/reload intellisense start working but then i did windows restart and problem returned

Comment: Don't know if it can help, however, I use it when want to set all settings to default. Try it: Tools->Import and Export settings->Reset all settings.

Answer (score 0):

Close the view and re-open it

Also, you can try the shortcut key `Ctrl + Space` to show up the Intellisence

Comment: tried that too.. it seems problem about projects which I've moved from another pc. now i made new project and there works intellisense

Answer (score 0):

Set the .net version from your project properties to latest.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the hidden .suo file in your folder structure, also delete the componentmodelcache stored in the visual studio folder in your c drive.It will be something similar to:

C:\Users\yournamehere\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0

AppData folder will also be hidden.

Hope it helps